# After a key is pressed, loop until key it is released

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

I need to wait until a key is pressed, then loop(incrementing a counter) until it is released. This is what I tried so far:

```
unsigned long readKeyLength()
{
    unsigned long toReturn = 0;
    int keyPressed;
    while (!_kbhit());
    while (keyPressed = _kbhit())
    {
        fgetc(stdin); // To remove the character from the buffer
        toReturn++;
    }
    return toReturn;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned long keyLength = 0;
    SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), 0); // Disable line buffering
    printf("Press a key\r\n");
    keyLength = readKeyLength();
    return 0;
}
```

The program correctly waits until a key is pressed, but then just loops one time inside `while (keyPressed = _kbhit())`.
I think that this happens because `fgetc` removes the character from the input buffer and then (even if I'm still pressing a key on the keyboard) the character isn't put in the stdin again.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: You are missing the halt-and-catch-fire statement `while (!_kbhit());` in your loop.  Consider `_getch()` instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, but I don't understand, could you expand please?
Where should I put the `while (!_kbhit());` in my loop? If I put it before clearing the buffer it will be useless, if I put it after clearing the buffer it will obviously run "forever" (or better, until another key is pressed)

Comment: You need to define a good exit condition for your while() loop.  Right now you quit when no key is hit, that only ever produces 1 as the return value since you cannot possibly type fast enough.  Incrementing toReturn while the key is down doesn't make sense either, that zips to INT_MAX, and beyond, in no time flat.  What *should* happen is impossible to guess from the snippet.  If you want to replace the default buffered input of the console then you need a buffer to store typed characters and exit the loop when, say, the Enter key is pressed.

Comment: @HansPassant What I need to do is "Incrementing toReturn while the key is down" (it takes a lot of seconds to reach 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF). I think that in my case it makes sense because I'm "recording" the length of a dot in morse code, so it will be pressed for less than a second. (I'm OK to go in error if the user press the key for long enough to reach INT_MAX). I also would like to avoid using `time`

Comment: Is it any key, or a specific key that your user is entering morse with?

Comment: @theB I would like to let the user use any key he wants

Comment: You cannot get a key-up notification from the C runtime library.  Intentionally avoiding time.h is a mistake, you'll have to limit the damage it incurs by using ReadConsoleInput().  The KEY_EVENT_RECORDs it returns gives you both key-down and key-up notifications.

Comment: Expanding on what @HansPassant said, an alternative solution would  be to create a message only window, sink the keyboard input into it with something like Raw Input, and listen to `WM_INPUT`/`WM_KEYDOWN/KEYUP` messages using the system's tick count to determine how long (relatively) the key was pressed. You'd still have some inaccuracy depending on how quickly you process the messages, but in the long run any error is likely to be small. That way you're not spinning indefinitely burning cycles.